# Custom config file for Active directory

Tags: php, html

Can Anyone please let me know the procedure to create a custom configuration file for active directory in PHP so that I could load the configuration from the file and connect to the directory?

Comment: What are you talking about?  What configuration file?  You want PHP to create the conifg or is this a config for a PHP Active DIrectory class?  You're gonna need to give us a lot more details.

Comment: config for a PHP Active DIrectory class... I want to create a PHP file which has the cofig for Active Directly so that when I change the hostname , I can go change in the config file without changing my actual code....

Comment: $server='137.65.138.159';
$admin='cn=admin,o=novell';
$passwd='novell';

$ds=ldap_connect($server);  // assuming the LDAP server is on this host

if ($ds) {
    // bind with appropriate dn to give update access
    $r=ldap_bind($ds, $admin, $passwd);
    if(!$r) die("ldap_bind failed<br>");

    echo "ldap_bind success";
    ldap_close($ds);
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect to LDAP server";
}

Comment: want these configurations to be stored in a file and then access this file in my code

Comment: You should probably not post your IP, username, and password.

Comment: Put them in a file, then use `include 'conifg.php';` to read it.  Docs: http://php.net/include

Comment: Are you wanting a specific apache server setting for each directory?